# What is the font used by Vogue Questions series?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What is the font that is used in Vogue Questions vlog series? It is kind of looks like Didot (since the characters are tall) but I don't think it is exactly Didot.

Anyone worked with a similar typeface before?

[image: 73 Q's with Gigi Hadid]

[image: 73 Q's with Chrissy Teigen]

[image: 73 Q's with Priyanka Chopra]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font is Bodoni by Linotype.

https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/bodoni

[image: Bodoni font sample from Fonts.com]